# What's the difference between these SATA cables?

Tags: hard-drive, sata, cable

I recently bought a new power supply and there were two slightly different SATA cables.

Here's a picture:
[image]

In the picture on the left, all 4 connectors are identical, but in the picture on the right, the three middle ones are about half the height (the end bits of the connectors are the same). What's the difference between them? Which one should I use to connect my HDDs?

Comment: The only difference I can see is the way the plugs are attached to the cables; one set is a push-fit, the other is a clip-cut. The picture is too low-rez to discern any greater detail.

Comment: @Tetsujin : The resolution of the picture is 4896x3672 if you click on it. Here I zoomed in on the difference I am asking about: https://i.ibb.co/z8k5RX7/asd.png

Comment: The dimensions of the picture are that, sure, but the dimensions of any individual plug in that image is about 200x100px & nowhere near enough to discern any greater detail than I already mentioned. A phone at 1m from a black object with black wires is not really the precision instrument required for detailed examination. Still my best guess is that the only difference is how the plugs clip to the wiring. The one on the left requires a section of cable to be bared before insertion, the right penetrates the cabling as it's squeezed shut.

Comment: Black color matters. It requires sufficient lighting and adequate positioning of the connectors to identify them. Try to make a picture of them held by a heavy book.for hands-free photographing.
Tetsujin is right with his comment.